# Как получить производительную видеокарту при старте приложения на ПК с 2+ видеокартами?

Tags: windows, delphi, opengl, gpu

Пишу Windows VCL приложение на Delphi 11 с 3D графикой использующее OpenGL.

Инициализация как во всех обычных уроках с `dglOpenGL.pas`:

```
h_DC := GetDC(Handle); // Хэндл панели на которой будет рисование

// Request opDoubleBuffered to allow for V-Sync control
h_RC := CreateRenderingContextVersion(h_DC, [opDoubleBuffered], 3, 3, False, 24, aDepthBits, 0, 0, 0, 0);

wglMakeCurrent(h_DC, h_RC);

ReadOpenGLCore;

  ...
```

При запуске приложение, на некоторых ПК (обычно ноутбуках), автоматом выбирается менее-производительная видеокарта (например встроенная Intel, а не дискретная NVidia).

Знаю, что пользователь настройками может указать какую карту назначить приложению или вообще. Вопрос про случай, когда пользователь этого явно не указал ("Автовыбор"). Как мне из своего приложения "попросить" у ОС более производительную видеокарту? Может быть как-то в манифесте указать, или еще как-то?

Comment: Что-то там всё сложно, похоже https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036292/select-a-graphic-device-in-windows-opengl

Comment: Такой вот сниппет еще советуют - https://gist.github.com/BeRo1985/939241b471f776ab844657d28d59368c. Костыли какие-то )

Comment: Это может регулироваться пользовательскими настройками и текущим режимом энергопотребления.

Comment: @user7860670 разумеется речь про "автовыбор". Уточнил это в вопросе.

Comment: А чем эти костыли не устраивают?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat для начала сгодится, но хотелось бы без asm и без такого обилия IFDEFов. C код, к примеру, достаточно лаконичен. Неужели Делфа так не умеет? Кстати вот вариант попроще на вид - https://github.com/peardox/Tilely/blob/607c687a447c8f04a80a1c6c2274c139be04ed34/TilelyLaz.lpr#L18

Comment: А там не нужен ни ассемблер, ни IFDEFы. Надо просто экспортировать флажек 4 байта Int c заданным именем